# I am not getting meterpreter sessions when I am connected to an Openvpn

Tags: vpn, metasploit, kali-linux, openvpn, meterpreter

I have a router and the ports required for the backdoor to connect back to the listener are forwarded to my machine's internal ip.
It all works fine only when I am not using VPN.

But after connecting to a VPN I don't get any sessions. Also tried to host apache server on my machine with VPNn connected but it also
doesn't show up but without VPN it works.

So if anyone else has encountered such problem and has found a solution to it
then help me out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a session both the attacker and victim machine should be on same network.

**A little background on VPN**

When you are connected to a VPN, you are probably on a private network and the victim is simply connected to the internet.
This makes the difference, in order to a get a session you have to be on same network but right now both the attacker and victim are on different network as you are connected to your VPN.

So, in oder to get a session you will have to connect the victim machine to the same VPN as yours. This is because VPN can connect your machine into remote LAN.

**NOTE :**
This will only happen when you are using your VPN IP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact setup, but remember that the VPN terminates at the VPN host, therefore if you then route out to the internet you will be appearing as if you are coming from the VPN hosts Public IP. This means the router forwarding you have isn't being used.

If your using a VPN then you need the VPN provider to allow incoming connections to their network to be routed over the VPN back to your machine (slightly simplified). But I don't think you will get that.

How about getting a host setup on a cloud provider that can accept incoming connections then from that host have a VPN tunnel setup back your network/client?